# curl Flask web service inside Docker container

Tags: docker, flask

I've got a Flask web service running in a Docker container on port 5000. How do I curl this service from inside the container? I can curl it from outside, i.e. the host, using `curl http://localhost:5000/<path>`.

Comment: when you say inside the container are you running: `docker exec -it <some container> bash` or are you trying to curl it internally using a script?  either way, it should be the same: `curl http://localhost:5000/<path>`

Comment: I enter the container using `docker exec -it <container name or ID> bash`, and then try to `curl` inside.

Comment: is the service running on port 5000 inside as well?  if so then curl that port same as above, else use the port the application was started on inside the container.

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
sudo docker inspect --format='{{json .NetworkSettings.Ports}}' <containername or container id>
```

In the network section look at ports.

```
{
  "443/tcp": [
    {
      "HostIp": "0.0.0.0",
      "HostPort": "8443"
    }
  ],
  "80/tcp": [
    {
      "HostIp": "0.0.0.0",
      "HostPort": "8080"
    }
  ]
}
```

As you can see my container is listening on port 80 and 443 so if I use curl inside the container I should use these ports. On the other hand from the docker host I should use HostPorts.

Alternatively you can look at the `Dockerfile` to view which ports are exposed.